# Django, Queue and Thread - don't free memory

Tags: python, django, multithreading

User visit http://example.com/url/ and invoke `page_parser` from `views.py`. `page_parser` create instance of `class Foo` from `script.py`.
Each time http://example.com/url/ is visited I see that memory usage goes up and up. I guess Garbage Collector don't collect instantiated `class Foo`. Any ideas why is it so?

Here is the code:

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from script import Foo
from script import urls

# When user visits http://example.com/url/ I run `page_parser`
def page_parser(request):
    Foo(urls)
    return HttpResponse("alldone")
```

script.py:

```
import requests

from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


class Newthread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, result):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.result = result

    def run(self):
        while True:
            url = self.queue.get()
            data = requests.get(url) # Download image at url
            self.result.append(data)
            self.queue.task_done()


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, urls):
        self.result = list()
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.startthreads()
        for url in urls:
            self.queue.put(url)
        self.queue.join()

    def startthreads(self):
        for x in range(3):
            worker = Newthread(queue=self.queue, result=self.result)
            worker.daemon = True
            worker.start()


urls = [
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/106399/pexels-photo-106399.jpeg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/164516/pexels-photo-164516.jpeg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/206172/pexels-photo-206172.jpeg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/32870/pexels-photo.jpg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/106399/pexels-photo-106399.jpeg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/164516/pexels-photo-164516.jpeg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/206172/pexels-photo-206172.jpeg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/32870/pexels-photo.jpg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/32870/pexels-photo.jpg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/106399/pexels-photo-106399.jpeg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/164516/pexels-photo-164516.jpeg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/206172/pexels-photo-206172.jpeg",
    "https://static.pexels.com/photos/32870/pexels-photo.jpg"]
```

Comment: Without knowing specifics, I see daemonized threads in an endless loop without a termination condition and a queue that is not being unset. So it kinda works as expected.

Comment: @Melvyn when I create instance of `class Foo` not in Django view, script get finished (it download all urls and process is closed somehow). Can you point me to the right direction - I want to terminate all Queue and Thread when I use script in Django view.

Comment: @Melvyn From your comment I guess it:
a) add `break` in while loop when specific item is get out of Queue b) put specific items in Queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several moving parts involved, but what I think happens is the following:

1. WSGI processes are not killed after each request, so things may persist.
2. You create 3 new threads, but don't let them join the main thread again, for example when the queue is empty.
3. Since the reference count to `Foo.queue` never reaches zero (as the threads are still alive waiting for new queue items), it cannot be garbage collected

So you keep creating new threads, new Foo classes and none of them can be freed.

I'm not an expert on queue.Queue, but my theory can be verified if you can watch the number of threads in the WSGI process go up with 3 each request (for example using `top(1)`).

As a side note, this is a side-effect of your class design. You do everything in `__init__`, which should really only be assigning class attributes.